# Opening a program as a different user (with /savecred) fails

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, uac, runas, batch

What I'm trying to do is run a second instance (my personal account) of dropbox.

I have a second user account setup, Dropbox installed, the Dropbox folder on the second acct shared properly. Everything works exactly as expected if I launch the second instance using:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:*[UserName]* *[DropboxLocation]*
```

But doesn't work when I try to launch using:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:*[UserName]* *[DropboxLocation]*
```

I launched it using CMD and got the following Error Message:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - *[DropboxLocation]*
1311: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

*Note: FYI, I have already verified that the first line works in the command prompt without issue.*

What I'm trying to do is save the credentials so I can move the shortcut to the startup folder, making it launch automatically when I login in to my primary account.

How do I go about fixing this issue and I'm correct in assuming that I should be able to launch an application as a different user on startup without having to enter the password every time (ie. this is the first time I have tried this in Windows 7).

*Note: One potential cause of the issue is that the primary acct exists on a different domain than the secondary acct. I tried both the 'username@domain' and 'domain\username' forms in the 'runas' but yielded the same results (works without, but fails with '/savecred'). The primary acct uses a different domain, the secondary acct uses the computer name as the domain (ie. it's local).*

**Update: I'm running Windows 7 Professional SP1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `C:\> runas /?`:

> /savecred:  to use credentials previously saved by the user.
>
> **This option is not available on Windows 7 Home or Windows 7 Starter Editions and will be ignored.**

If you are not running a Home or Starter edition of Windows 7 please update your question to provide more details on your version and network setup.

Additionally, `/savecred` is ONLY for the user who ran the `Runas /Savecred`.  So if you use Savecred, and give the password, *you* won't have to enter it again, but other users would have to repeat the /savecred, and enter the password, to have the credentials saved for their use.

You can see which credentials are cached in the Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel>User Accounts>Credential Manager)

Comment: I should have figured that. Either way, I'm running Professional so that isn't the issue. I also added some more info that may help.